# Tools to manage solo software project

Tags: project-management, workflow, issue-tracker, requirements-management

I will describe exactly what I'm looking to do that suits my subjective most productive way of working on solo projects (no collaboration with anyone whatsoever) that people may or may not agree with but I'm just looking for software and tool suggestions that satisfy my requirements listed below (no critique of them).

Before listing my requirements I will present a hypothetical project as an example. Let's say I want to create a plugin for a pdf reader that will allow me to make notes over arbitrary words or passages in the text of the document. Let's say that I want to list a number of TODOs in my project management solution e.g.:

1. Display a text area after pressing a Ctr + N while having highlighted some text in the document. The text area will have a Save button below it.
2. Store the note in a database and link it to the piece of previously highlighted text.
3. Display an asterisk next to the text that when clicked will display the note that was previously made while simultaneously re-highlighting the text over which that note was made.
4. etc etc

What I need is:

1. Use Git. Have a master branch with code that is currently in production. Have a development branch to which I merge features for the next release. Merge development branch to master when I decide to make the next release to production.
2. Be able to have the previously mentioned list of TODOs and to add stuff to it and make "sub" TODOs if I decide that a specific step needs to be broken down into smaller ones.
3. Have four columns: "To be done", "Under development", "Completed Development" and "Released to Production".
4. Have everything automatically move from the "Completed Development" column to "Released to Production" whenever I merge from develop branch to master. This is a nice to have feature but I can do without it.
5. Group items in "Released to production" column under a release tag. Would be nice to have it happen automatically.
6. Hide previous releases from "Released to production" column.

Not needed features:

1. Collaboration with others.
2. Differentiate  features from bugs.
3. Make extensive documentation and description of requirements.
4. CI/CD.

Other notes:

1. I need something that I can edit quickly and easily
2. I would prefer something lighter and simpler than Jira.
3. It can also be a plugin for eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Trello seems to be simple enough for my needs. Can create columns and creating items in each column is fast and easy. Projects are hosted on online account and as such accessible from anywhere (web portal + android app). It's free too.

I don't yet know if it'll satisfy my 4, 5, 6 requirements need to work with it a bit.